# my nodejs server crashed when i use async await code

Tags: node.js, async-await

if i use async the server crashes, and the error will not be handled

```
app.get('/', async(req:Request, res:Response) => {
  throw new Error('Error connecting to database');
  res.send('Hello World!');
});

app.use((err: Error, req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  console.error(err);
  res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
});
```

instead if i use with out async every thing works as expected,

```
app.get('/', (req:Request, res:Response) => {
  throw new Error('Error connecting to database');
  res.send('Hello World!');
});

app.use((err: Error, req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  console.error(err);
  res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
});
```

why is that happening, any fixes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just install npm i express-async-errors and import it in root file